# Mongo c driver find query error handling

Tags: c, mongodb

Isn't there a way to control if there is an error in the find query, which is done using `mongoc_collection_find` API function,  when using mongo c driver?

For example, I am passing the following query

```
{ "$a" : true }
```

As a field name cannot start with `$a`, usually `mongodb` would print some kind of error message(for example if I execute the same query in mongo shell), but for the mongo c driver, I didn't find any way to control if there is an error within the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strangely enough, the error can be only found after executing the `next` function of the cursor returned by the find query.

So basically, it works this way:

```
mongoc_cursor_t *cursor = mongoc_collection_find(collection, flags, skip, limit,
                                                 batch_size, query, fields, read_prefs);
if (mongoc_cursor_more(cursor)) {
    mongoc_cursor_next(cursor,doc);
    bson_error_t error;
    // The error can be "discovered" in this level
    if (mongoc_cursor_error(cursor, &error))
        std::cout << error.message << std::endl; 
}
```